# codeigniter failed to access MySQL on user, but logs in just fine with root

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I actually fixed my problem, I just wanted to post my solution.

If someone wants to offer further thoughts for those after us that find this post, that's fine too.

---

All of my codeigniter files were copied over. So I knew my php code should have been fine.
My DB was exported as a .SQL file, so I didn't think that could be the problem either.

And I deleted / recreated the user several times, trying to figure out what I did wrong.

- Username: smellysocks
- Password: smelliersocks
- Host: %
- Type: database-specific
- ALL PRIVILEGES (minis GRANT, all database-specific of course)

Eventually I changed the host type to "localhost", as that was the only difference I could find. In my mind this should not have fixed the problem, but the code runs fine now with no problems.

Phrases I searched on Google for:

- "mysql only root works"
- "Codeigniter Filename: core/Loader.php  Line Number: 305"
- "Codeigniter Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings"
- "Codeigniter mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user"
- "Codeigniter A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user"

Comment: Where is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

A host value of % does not include localhost for sockets and thus must be specified if you want to connect using any method. further [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html) [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1) [link](https://creechy.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/mysql-userlocalhost-and-user/)